# Can Blazor's AuthorizeView check role AND issuer of that role?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication, asp.net-authorization

I am transforming claims of the existing ClaimsPrincipal (WindowsPrincipal to be precise - I'm using Windows Authentication):

```cs
var gym1 = new ClaimsIdentity();
var gym1Claims = new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Member", null, "Gym1")
};
gym1.AddClaims(gym1Claims);

var gym2 = new ClaimsIdentity();
var gym2Claims = new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Member", null, "Gym2"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "VIPMember", null, "Gym2"),
};
gym2.AddClaims(gym2Claims);

user.AddIdentity(gym1);
user.AddIdentity(gym2);
```

Is it possible to check assigned roles as well as the issuer ("Gym1", "Gym2"...) in the `AuthorizeView` component? Right now it doesn't care about which gym membership I'm identifying with.

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="VIPMember">
    <Authorized>
        <p>You can use VIP lounge</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>You're not authorized.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with Policy based Authorization, a minimal example here:

```
public class RoleIssuserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public RoleIssuserRequirement(string role, string issuer)
        {
            Role = role;
            Issuer = issuer;
        }

        public string  Issuer { get; set; }

        public string  Role { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleIssuerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RoleIssuserRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleIssuserRequirement requirement)
        {
            var Roles = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role );

            var expectrole = Roles.Where(x => x.Value == requirement.Role && x.Issuer == requirement.Issuer);

            

            if (expectrole.Count()!=0)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Regist the services:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(x => x.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new RoleIssuserRequirement("Vip","Gym1")))); 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleIssuerHandler>();
```

Razor components:

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="MyPolicy">
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified it to do claim based authorization by having a policy for each claim. It works like a charm.